# Guava CacheBuilder prevent load for specific values

Tags: java, caching, guava

I have the following java code to build a Guava cache:

```
myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .build(new CacheLoader<Result, String>() {
                       @Override
                       public Result load(String s) throws Exception {
                          Result result = getResult(s);

                          // if (result == Result.INVALID) return ???

                          return result;
                       }
                   }
            );
```

I would like to add some code whereby if the result is a specific value then nothing is loaded into the cache.
Not sure how to do it.
Any suggestions?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: just throw an exception. See [`CacheLoader` docs](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#load%28K%29):

```
Returns:
  the value associated with key; must not be null
Throws:
  Exception - if unable to load the result
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
    myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .build(new CacheLoader<Result, String>() {
                   @Override
                   public Result load(String s) throws Exception {
                      Result result = getResult(s);
                      if (result == Result.INVALID) {
                          throw new InvalidResultException();
                      }
                      return result;
                   }
               }
        );
```

and you should use `get(K)` or `getUnchecked(K)` to handle the exception accordingly, see [Guava wiki about caches](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#population).

Please note that in [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), a Guava cache successor, you can return null from a [`CacheLoader#load(K)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/latest/com.github.benmanes.caffeine/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/CacheLoader.html) to indicate the value was not loaded:

```
Returns:
the value associated with key or null if not found
Throws:
Exception - or Error, in which case the mapping is unchanged
```

For more info, [see Caffeine wiki about cache population](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population).